# Add Border Color to all tables Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Trying to add a border color to all tables in Powerpoint and failing. I'm not very good at this.

```
Sub SetTableBorder()
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oSld As Slide

For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSl.Shapes
        If oShp.HasTable Then
            With oShp.Table
                .Borders(ppBorderTop).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(235,186,182)
                .Borders(ppBorderBottom).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(235,186,182)
                .Borders(ppBorderLeft).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(235,186,182)
                .Borders(ppBorderRight).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(235,186,182)
            End With
        End If
   Next oShp
Next oSld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, correct the typo:  oSl.Shapes --> oSld.Shapes
Next, add Option Explicit above all the subs/functions in this (and ideally all other) module. That'll prevent this kind of thing from biting you.

Next, you want to work with the table's .Rows(1).Cells.Borders(ppBorderTop) and its various properties to set the top border,

Something like .Rows(.Rows.Count).Cells ... etc to set the bottom border for the table.

Then similarly, .Columns(1).Cells ... properties ... to set the left border.

And so on.